# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 19. Setting up multiple tinyproxy servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tinyproxy

So I'm trying to set up multiple proxy servers through tinyproxy with ubuntu on AWS. Is there a way to setup it way quicker without having to connect to each instance 1 by 1 and download the packages then setup the server? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to find a way to run batch commands on multiple instances to provision them.

You can look into SSM Run Command to accomplish this. This will allow you to run Ansible playbooks, Shell commands, etc. on multiple instances based on tags / resource groups / manual selection.

[Further reading from AWS regarding Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html)